# flyway and initialization of Repeatable migrations

Tags: database-migration, flyway

Quoting flyway doc at https://flywaydb.org/documentation/migration/repeatable :

> Repeatable migrations do not have a version. Instead they are
>   (re-)applied every time their checksum changes.
>
> This is very useful for managing database objects whose definition can
>   then simply be maintained in a single file in version control.
>
> Within a single migration run, repeatable migrations are always
>   applied last, after all pending versioned migrations have been
>   executed. Repeatable migrations are applied in the order of their
>   description.

This sounds exciting however I can't seem to find any clarification on how this actually works and on how to initialize repeatable migrations. I understand that for Versioned migration I can create a base migration (https://flywaydb.org/documentation/existing) and then run the baseline command to get things ready for my future versions. However for **repeatable migrations** I do not understand how flyway is able to checksum changes.

> Instead they are
>
> > (re-)applied every time their checksum changes.

Is flyway making the assumption I am recreating my database from scratch to get the checksum comparison working? This would explain how it is able to compare checksum (since it has access to the file-definition of object already in database).

Comment: The first link is broken, I think this is the right place now: https://flywaydb.org/documentation/concepts/migrations#repeatable-migrations. The second link redirects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**: I know it s been some time, the solution I was looking for is flyway repair. It will sync a pre-existing schema with flyway internal checksum table. https://flywaydb.org/documentation/commandline/repair

I've tested flyway and now understand initialization: flyway will ignore existing scripts / migrations as long as the file name will not have a specific prefix (I think 'REPEATABLE' is the default) - so as long as migrations are not renamed to be executed flyway will ignore them.

Comment: Yes, correct, Flyway doesn't go investigating what tables exist in your database or anything like that, it only relies on what it itself stored in schema_version previously. The prefix is just "R" and can be [configured](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/api/javadoc/org/flywaydb/core/Flyway.html#setRepeatableSqlMigrationPrefix-java.lang.String-)

Answer (score 8):

Let's assume the checksum of your repeatable migration SQL script is e.g. 123.

1. First time you run Flyway it will check schema_version table, find out this repeatable migration has not been applied yet so it will execute it.
2. Second time you launch Flyway it will check that your SQL script has its checksum equal to 123 which is equal to what's recorded in schema_version since last time and so your repeatable migration script won't be executed.
3. Now let's assume you modify your repeatable migration SQL script for the third version and the checksum changes to e.g. 987. When you launch Flyway it will find out that 987 is not equal to what's still stored in schema_version (123) so this time it will execute the new version of the repeatable migration SQL and then update the 123 checksum value in schema_version to 987.

This means you can keep on changing repeatable migration scripts with each new version as you need. You cannot update the baseline (non-repeatable) script this way because Flyway would throw an error about non-matching checksum.

Comment: Thanks I understand how flyway is able to detect changes AFTER initialization - once it has a hash for the sql code. While testing I found out there is no magic here and the first time a repeatable migration is detected then flyway will run it. This makes things not too easy when working with a non empty project.

Comment: Ok, so the repeatable scripts will run only if you change the script? I am creating synonyms for another user with an R script, I added a new table and noticed that there is no synonym for the new table. Now I know why, but can I make the R script run every time?